# How can I replace all duplicate white spaces in a string with tabs

Tags: regex, bash

I have the following string:

```
'1   NXA-PAC-1100W-B      AC    1080.00     90.00     ok'
```

I'm trying to convert the white spaces between the words to single tabs using sed, but the spacing in the output does not appear to be equal. What am I doing wrong here?

**command**:

```
echo '1   NXA-PAC-1100W-B      AC    1080.00     90.00     ok' | sed 's/\s\s\+/\t/g'
```

**result**:

```
'1       NXA-PAC-1100W-B AC      1080.00 90.00   ok'
```

Comment: Did you consider using [`unexpand`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unexpand)?

Comment: Do I understand you correct, and do you need to remove one `\s`? This seems to work: `echo '1   NXA-PAC-1100W-B      AC    1080.00     90.00     ok' | sed 's/\s\+/\t/g'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+` means "one or more", so in your example you're specifying a space plus one or more spaces, therefore two or more spaces. You just want

```
echo '1   NXA-PAC-1100W-B      AC    1080.00     90.00     ok' | sed 's/\s\+/\t/g'
```

Or more verbose but more posix-y

```
echo '1   NXA-PAC-1100W-B      AC    1080.00     90.00     ok' | sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/\t/g'
```

There is possibly some misunderstanding about how tabs work in your statement "the spacing in the output does not appear to be equal". But there isn't enough information for me to know for sure and I don't want to insult you if there is not.

Comment: I think `\+` is a GNU extension to BRE, so even more posix-y for "at least one space" would be `[[:space:]][[:space:]]*`.

Comment: thanks! Unfortunately I had misunderstood how tabs work in this case, I was mainly just trying to get an equal amount of spacing in between each word (4-5 spaces for example), so the output would resemble "1    NXA-PAC-1100W-B    AC    1080.00    90.00    ok" (4 spaces between each word. I was able to get the job done though by going with sed 's/\s\+/    /g'. Thanks for clarifying the issue with my '+', definitely helped out a lot